# Cases with condition vs Select inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, pattern-matching, conditional

I tried to plot integer points that fall into a 2D region that's dynamically changed. So I resort to `Cases` and `Select`, but `Cases` with `Condition` is not working expectedly. Here is the simplifed version of my code and result:

```
region[u_] := u <= x + y <= u + 2;
intPoints = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 13}, {y, 0, 13}], 1];
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   {ListPlot[intPoints], 
    RegionPlot[region[u], {x, 0, 13}, {y, 0, 13}]},
   {ListPlot[Cases[intPoints, {x_, y_} /; region[u]]],
    ListPlot[Cases[intPoints, {x_, y_} /; Evaluate[region[u]]]],
    ListPlot[Select[intPoints, region[u] /. {x -> #[[1]], y -> #[[2]]} &]]}}],
 {u, 0, 13}
 ]
```

[image]

I don't understand why inside `Cases` the point coordinates ***x*** and ***y*** won't go into ***region*** for the `Condition` to be evaluated. Does it first do the replacement of ***x*** and ***y*** and then do the evaluation? But why the additional `Evaluate` operation still doesn't help?

Could someone elaborate me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cases` could not '*see*' `x` and `y` from the pattern `{x_,y_}` (`Condition` has `Attribute` `HoldAll`); it could have been resolved using `Evaluate` around `region[u]`.

In short, use `Initialization`; allows for better control over the content of `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 (* expr *)
 grid[u],

 (* control *)
 {u, 0, 13},

 (* init *)
 Initialization :> (
   (* points *)
   intPoints = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 13}, {y, 0, 13}], 1];

   (* redefined region function; making point coordinates explicit *)
   region[u_, x_, y_] := u <= x + y <= u + 2;

   (* list plot *)
   listPlot = ListPlot[intPoints];

   (* region plot *)
   regionPlot[u_] := RegionPlot[region[u, x, y], {x, 0, 13}, {y, 0, 13}, PlotLabel -> RegionPlot];

   (* list plot - Cases *)
   listPlotCases[u_] := ListPlot[Cases[intPoints, {x_, y_} /; region[u, x, y]], PlotLabel -> Cases, PlotRange -> {{0, 13}, {0, 13}}];

   (* list plot - Select *)
   listPlotSelect[u_] := ListPlot[Select[intPoints, region[u, #[[1]], #[[-1]]] &], PlotLabel -> Select, PlotRange -> {{0, 13}, {0, 13}}];

   (* assemble output *)
   grid[u_] := Grid[{
      {listPlot, regionPlot[u]},
      {listPlotCases[u], listPlotSelect[u]},
      {Style[StringTemplate["u=``"][u], Red, Bold, Large], SpanFromLeft}
      }];
   ),
 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 LocalizeVariables -> True
]
```

The code above outputs

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I learned some good practice from your code. I  still need to understand why `Evaluate[region[u]]` won't work. And when I set `LocalizeVariables -> False`, this line `ListPlot[Cases[intPoints, {x_, y_} /; Evaluate[region[u]]]]` actually works inside `Manipulate`, just like it works inside `Dynamic`. Could you help me explain why this is the case? Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome! it's nice to know the answer was helpful; I think it would be instructive to evaluate `Manipulate[aHead[{x_, y_} /; region[u]] // FullForm, {u, 0, 13}, 
 LocalizeVariables -> False]`  with `LocalizeVariables` set to `False`/`True` (defaults to `True`) and with using/not using `Evaluate`; notice what happens to the variables